# google calendar api asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i create a new calendar "test" and i use this code

```
 public static CalendarService GetService(string applicationName, string userName, string password)
    {
        CalendarService service = new CalendarService(applicationName);
        service.setUserCredentials(userName, password);
        return service;
    }
    public static void AddEvent(CalendarService service, string title, string contents, string location, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry entry = new Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry();

        // Set the title and content of the entry.
        entry.Title.Text = title;
        entry.Content.Content = contents;

        // Set a location for the event.
        Where eventLocation = new Where();
        eventLocation.ValueString = location;
        entry.Locations.Add(eventLocation);

        When eventTime = new When(startTime, endTime);
        entry.Times.Add(eventTime);

        Uri postUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/test/private/full");

        // Send the request and receive the response:
        AtomEntry insertedEntry = service.Insert(postUri, entry);
    }

AddEvent(GetService("regis-test", vUserName, vPassword), "title", "test", "Sibiu", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(4));
```

what is wrong ? becouse this code do not add event to the test calendar he add to the default

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the Uri to reflect the calendar ID.

I have created a test calendar on my gmail account and was able to create a calendar event using the following URI for my calendar:

```
Uri postUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/hsi9s9tlvgkugbub8r42kv9ugk@group.calendar.google.com/private/full");
```

To find the calendar ID for your test calendar you need to do the following:

Select your test calendar in the left menu under "My calendars" and press settings.

[image: Calendar settings]

Then select your calendar:

[image]

In the next screen you see your calendar ID under Calendar Address:
[image: calendar-id]

Use the id for your Uri:

```
Uri postUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/hsi9s9tlvgkugbub8r42kv9ugk@group.calendar.google.com/private/full");
```

Here is a screenshot of a calendar event created through C# code on the test calendar:
[image: Entry added]